# How to get first object from List<Object> using Hibernate.initialize()?

Tags: java, hibernate

Example:

```
@OneToMany(fetch=FetchType.LAZY, mappedBy="album", cascade=CascadeType.ALL)
private List<Photo> listPhoto;

List<Album> albums = (List<Album>) criteria.list();
for(Album album : albums) {
  Hibernate.initialize(album.getListPhoto().get(0));
}
```

When i do this, brings me all Object from List, i just need First Object, even when .get(0)

Comment: You're missing some some crucial parts of your code, and it's not really clear what you're trying to do.

Comment: I think you should implement LIMIT to your criteria

Comment: Initialize is used to remove proxies and replace them with the real content. You can't use it to start a specific query. Use a DAO to fetch the wanted entity.